# Meter push new object to array in collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collection2

I am trying to update a collection by pushing to an already existing array in the collection.

Here is the update function I am trying to run:

```
Games.update({ _id: game._id }, {
  $push: { players: { name: playerName } },
});
```

Here is the error I am getting in the console:

```
update failed: MongoError: Cannot update 'players' and 'players' at the same time
```

Relevant schemas:

```
Player = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    label: 'name',
    max: 50,
  },
});

Schemas.Game = new SimpleSchema({
  ...
  players: {
    type: [Player],
    label: 'Players',
    autoValue: function () {
      return [];
    },
  },
});
```

I am using the `autoValue` for the `players` array to sort of initialize it when a new game is created. Could this be a problem for when the first player is added?

Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had this same problem these days. I managed to go through by using defaultValue instead of autoValue. If all you want is to initialize the property, then defautValue is what you want anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited:** @Logiwan992 try using defaultValue instead of autoValue.I believe you're using autoValue to set the value of `players` so it isn't undefined. But with your implementation, autoValue would run when there is an update on your document.

`defaultValue` would run when the document is created first. But if you still choose to use `autoValue`, you may also want to check if it's an update and return `undefine`. As in this

`players: {
       type: [Player],
       label: 'Players',
       autoValue: function () {
           if (this.isUpdate) {
               return undefined;
           }
           return [];
       },
   },`

Returning undefined would ensure the new update value is used.
My recommendation though is to use

`players: {
       type: [Player],
       label: 'Players',
       defaultValue: [],
   },`

Comment: A short explanation why he should try using that would make this an answer.